# Why is 20% enrichment for uranium considered the minimum for making a nuke?

Tags: black-holes, nuclear-physics, radioactivity, nuclear-engineering

I get that this is the physical limit - an infinite mass of uranium would produce a runaway reaction. But an infinite mass is impossible.

Really, what is the minimum % of enrichment of uranium which, when stacked into a mass, runs away before becoming a black hole?

Comment: Why would uranium enrichment produce a black hole? As currently written, this thread needs to be closed as the question posed makes no sense at all.

Comment: the % enrichment is the proportion of the given mass that is enriched. It has nothing to do with the total amount of mass.

Comment: @Jim The OP is referring to *critical mass*, which is larger for lower levels of enrichment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriched_uranium) a minimum of $5.4\%$ $^{235}$U is required before the critical mass becomes finite. This is about seven or eight times as much $^{235}$U as is found in naturally occurring uranium. According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_mass) uranium enriched with $15\%$ $^{235}$U has a critical mass of over $600$ kg, and for $20\%$ $^{235}$U the critical mass is over $400$ kg.

It looks like the $20\%$ figure is a somewhat arbitrary threshold. Note that the two challenges in designing a fission bomb are assembling a critical configuration in a rapid but controlled way from sub-critical components and stopping the critical mass dispersing itself before a significant amount of energy has been released (a [“fizzle”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizzle_(nuclear_explosion))). Just stacking a critical mass of enriched uranium into a big pile will not create a nuclear explosion (although you would not want to be anywhere near it).